# Does NRVO happen in static member variables initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++20, static-members, return-value-optimization

I have got a class with a large static std::array that needs an expensive computation to be initialized, so i defined a static method to perform it. I don't know however if some copy happens or maybe the computation is performed inside the member array.

```
class A
{
  static inline array<double, 100000> a = fill_a();
  static array<double, 100000> fill_a() 
  {
    array<double, 100000> b;  
    /* large computation involving b with non constexpr functions */
    return b;
  }
};
```

How can I test if b is actually copied? Or if everything is done inside a?
Thanks for any help or tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what "NRVO" is. From context I *guess* you are referring to *copy elision*. Copy elision is allowed in a few cases. In particular, when returning a non-`volatile` local variable with the same type as the function's return type, copy elision is *permitted* (see [class.copy.elision] paragraph 1.1.

With C++17 copy-elision became mandatory in some contexts. However, in all of these cases the elided copy would copy a *prvalue* which isn't the case for a named variable, obviously. Thus, the compiler *can* elide the copy but it isn't *mandated* to do so. It is a Qualify of Implementatation issue.

As the effect of copy elision is that the object in question is constructed in the destination location and the destination location is know (in this case `&S::b`) it should be possible to `assert()` in cases where copy elision is not used, e.g.:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <array>

struct S
{   
    static std::array<double, 10> fill_a() {
        std::array<double, 10> b;
        assert(&a == &b);
        std::fill(b.begin(), b.end(), 0); 
        return b;
    }   
    static inline std::array<double, 10> a = fill_a();
};  

int main()
{   
    return S::a[0]; // reference S::a
}
```

Interestingly, the above code does `assert()` although I think `g++` normally implements copy elision in these cases. It is, unfortunately, quite possible that adding the `assert(&a == &b)`, or more precisely taking the address of the returned object, inhibits copy elision.

Otherwise, it would be necessary to observe side-effects of copying to determine that copy elision did *not* happen. Using `std::array<double, N>` doesn't have any observable side-effects. It is possible to use a custom class, though, e.g.:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>

struct C {
    int i = 0;
    C() = default;
    C(C &&){ std::cout << "moved\n"; };
    C(C const&){ std::cout << "copied\n"; };
};
struct S
{
    static std::array<C, 10> fill_a() {
        std::array<C, 10> b;
        c = &b;
        // assert(&a == &b);
        return b;
    }
    static inline std::array<C, 10>  a = fill_a();
    static inline std::array<C, 10>* c = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    assert(S::c == &S::a);
    return S::a[0].i; // reference S::a
}
```

That doesn't print anything about copying or moving `C` objects, even though the address of the local variable is taken and even the `assert()` in `main()` holds. However, when uncommenting the assert in `fill_a()` it fires! It can be verified that the side-effects would do the Right Thing by kind of making copy elision impossible, e.g., using

```
std::array<C, 10> fill_a() {
    std::array<C, 10> b, d;
    return std::rand() % 2? b: d;
}
```

Comment: NRVO == [Named Return Value Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization), just a special case of copy elision.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I do understand what the abbreviation is referring to but the C++ standard does not define it. The question is clearly about the C++ standard. However, the C++ standard doesn't use the term "NRVO" or "named return value optimization". It does use the term _copy elision_, though. Using correct terms turns out to be useful in resolving these questions.

Comment: @DavisHerring: fair enough. Thanks for pointing that out. All those C++ standard versions blend together for me :) I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to test your compiler here, since not all compilers will elide the copy, and whether they do so may be dependent on optimization settings.

There are two ways to do this, and I recommend doing them both on an optimized build.

1. Inspect the generated assembly code to see if the large array is constructed in static storage, or first as a stack temporary and then copied.
2. Wrap the array in a class whose copy constructor contains logging, use an object of that logging class instead of the array, and check to see if any copies are made.

#2 should take you no more than 5 minutes to test.  #1 is more complex but is a valuable skill to learn if you're doing work that is this performance sensitive.

Here is what I am envisioning for #2:

```
#include<array>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct S
{
    array<double, 100000> a;
    S() { puts("ctor"); }
    S(S const& rhs) : a(rhs.a) { puts("copy ctor"); }
    S(S const&& rhs) : a(rhs.a) { puts("move ctor"); }
};

class A
{
  static S fill_a() 
  {
    S b;  
    /* large computation involving b with non constexpr functions */
    return b;
  }
  inline static S a = fill_a();
};

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the potential of a copy can be detected comparing the addresses of `a` and `b`, e.g., using `assert(&a == &b);`? As the effect of copy elision is that the object is just constructed in its final location that should yield a hint on whether the array is being copied...